# SIM908 POST Request

Tags: gsm

I want to send a couple of variables to a webpage in my server over the SIM908. Does anyone know how do send such data over POST protocol? I was able to complete the task using GET but currently nothing is working for POST.

Comment: What is the POST protocol? Are you talking about the HTTP protocol? You say you can manage with GET, how did you do that? What are you trying with POST that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIM908 by SIMCom even though states it supports HTTP POST request, it supports only GET and not POST requests.

The only way around this is to send a set of carved TCP/IP packets that address a POST request.

I used wire-shark to capture the request done through my browser and stripped down the unnecessary information.

Afterwards, I included the same information in  the "data" field of the TCP/IP packet addressed to the server. I successfully received the intended response.

Answer (score 1):

Internet is mostly static for real time streaming try to change script variables so that every time they render with new values, this is the dynamic property.

You mean like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrDNd2BoEGA) that is implemented with tcp/ip stack [by Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00833b.pdf).

In that the graphical data is varied with in the micro-controller and sent via networking protocols.

You may find something in that, then incorporate into your project and send using SIM908 with AT&T commands.

I recommend you to add some extra information about your project (if you want to).